# Text field in Rails stores string instead of Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am designing a controller that handles the receipts for my E-commerce site. This is what the JSON params look like:

```
{
"receipt": {
    "items": {
        "item1": {
            "price": "22.11",
            "quantity": "2",
            "name": "Name",
            "discount": 0.04
        },
        "item2": {
            "price": 12.11,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "Name"
        },
        "item3": {
            "price": 21.11,
            "quantity": 1,
            "name": "Name",
            "discount": 0.14
        }
    },
    "payment_type": "Credit Card",
    "payment_provider": "Visa",
    "paid_status": true,
    "total": 22
    }
}
```

The items field is a text field in the database and I am using `serialize` to convert it to hash:

```
serialize :receiptitems, Hash
```

My strong params are defined in this way:

```
params.require(:receipt).permit(:payment_type, :payment_provider, :paid_status, :total, items: params[:receipt][:items].try(:keys))
```

Since the items are dynamically generated I now receive an error:

```
Unpermitted parameters: item1, item2, item3
```

How can I fix this? I tried `tap` method and it did not work as well.

Comment: params.require(:receipt).permit(:payment_type, :payment_provider, :paid_status, :total, *params[:receipt][:items].try(:keys))

Comment: So i still get the warning about the Unpermitted params but it is updating the record correctly. Thank you @Nishu

Comment: Actually does not work yet :(

Comment: Strong Paramters should allow you to permit nested attributes as follows:

```
params.require(:receipt).permit(:payment_type, :payment_provider, :paid_status, :total, items: [:price, :quantity, :name, :discount])
```

Comment: When i do that **ice** i get Unpermitted params on the key of the hash like **item1** for example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for  :price, :quality, :name, :discount
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html